# Boilerplate Can't create mvc controller class

Tags: model-view-controller, boilerplate

I use boilerplate asp.net mvc 5x - multi page web application.

I create all my database model,dto's,interfaces and services. But i could not see my interface into the .web solition/controllers

Here my entity

```
    public class WineType : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}
```

Here my IApplicationService

```
    interface IWineTypeService: IApplicationService
{
    List<WineTypeDto> List();
}
```

Here my Dto

```
    public class WineTypeDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}
```

And also here my service

```
    public class WineTypeService : testControllerAppServiceBase, IWineTypeService
{
    private readonly IRepository<testController.General.WineType> _wineTypeRepository;

    public WineTypeService(IRepository<testController.General.WineType> wineTypeRepository)
    {
        _wineTypeRepository = wineTypeRepository;
    }
    public List<WineTypeDto> List()
    {
        var list = _wineTypeRepository.GetAllList().Select(s => ObjectMapper.Map(s, new WineTypeDto())).ToList();
        list.ForEach(f =>
        {
            f.Icon = $"{GetCurrentHostUrl()}{f.Icon}";
        });
        return list;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem. In my visual studio 2017, i can not add mvc controller but in visual studio 2015 it works